# Intertwining 3 arrays in matlab / octave to get correct pattern

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I know I can intertwine 2 arrays by

```
C = [A(:),B(:)].';   %'
D = C(:)
```

But how can I intertwine *3 arrays* with a (pendulum type of pattern going back and forth) See image below with arrows showing the intertwining path pattern I'm trying to get *(each column is an array)*.  Also the number pattern I'm trying to get is also next to it, in one large column.  **Please note the numerical values are just examples to make it easier to read. the numerical values could be decimals also**

[image: number pattern]

I tried the code below but the pattern is incorrect.

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
C=[100,200,300,400,500]

D = [A(:),B(:),C(:)].';   %'
E = D(:)
```

I get an error in the **D array due to the fact that the B array is a larger size than A and C but the number pattern is also not following the pattern I'm trying to get.**

```
                 1
                10
               100
                 2
                20
               200
                 3
                30
               300
                 4
                40
               400
                 5
                50
               500
error: horizontal dimensions mismatch (5x1 vs 9x1)
```

The pattern from the 3 arrays I'm trying to get is below.

**Please note the numerical values are just examples to make it easier to read. the numerical values could be decimals also**

```
1
10
100
20
2
30
200
40
3
50
300
60
4
70
400
80
5
90
500
```

PS: I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
D = zeros(4 * size(A, 2) - 1, 1); % initialization
D(1 : 4 : end) = A;
D(2 : 2 : end) = B;
D(3 : 4 : end) = C;
```

Comment: I don't have MATLAB installed on my machine, but that should work.

Comment: I tried it but I get an error: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I....
The code I used was.   
*A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
C=[100,200,300,400,500]

D = zeros(4 * size(A,1) - 1, 1); % initialization
D(1 : 4 : end) = A;
D(2 : 2 : end) = B;
D(3 : 4 : end) = C;*

Comment: You're taking the size of the wrong dimension; `A` is a row vector. Try `D=zeros(4 * size(A,2) - 1, 1)`.

Comment: btw, I've confirmed that your updated code works on Octave 3.8.0